# How do I close all tabs in Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm using Chrome 32 on an Android **tablet** (*not* phone) and just can't figure out how to close all open tabs in one go.

Comment: [Here's a more-thorough answer, with more screenshots.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232571/121619) Be sure to click the number of tabs icon first or else the Close All Tabs option won't exist. Clicking the number of open tabs icon first forces the 3 dots menu to have different content.

Answer (score 7):

1. Click on Tabs icon in upper right corner
2. Go to options
3. Click on close all tabs

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Unfortunately your answer does not work on tablets. There is no such menu option visible in Chrome 32 on an Android tablet.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2391819), you can't.

You have to close tabs individually, at least on a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Android's settings, then to apps, then to Chrome, and cleared the data and the cache.  When I reopened Chrome, the tabs were all closed.  This was done on a Asus Memo 7 tablet.  I know it's combersome, but it beats manually closing 100+ tabs.