# How to Limit Number of Recent Activity Screens

Tags: applications, recents-screen

I'm amazed that A) I haven't looked for this sooner, and B) I couldn't find something that does this.

I simply want to limit the number of recent activity screens (cards) that appear when I hit the □ button.



[image]

**EDIT:**
My phone is an non-rooted LG Stylo 3 Plus, Android version 7.0 Software version TP45010m.
<sub>(Also, if anyone knows how to root *this phone specifically,* I'd like to hear it... I haven't been able to find a method that works for LG Stylo 3 Plus and have seen that this phone specifically is unable to be rooted.)</sub>
**

TL;DR:
Any time my 80-year-old mother asks me to help her with something on her smartphone (Does the day of the week end with "y"?), I tap the □ button to see her recent screens. She generally has like 47 recent cards listed there, as she never swipes them away or clears the list.

I'm aware of the concept that (generally speaking) these are more or less shortcuts to apps that have run, and that they (generally) use no memory while sleeping in this state, so swiping them away often won't conserve significant resources.

I'm also aware that I can "CLEAR ALL" cards (the button can be seen in my animation), but I don't want to do that, either.

The problem is that this is supposed to be an "easy" way to jump back and forth between apps that you use often, right? Doesn't it defeat that purpose if there are 47 cards to look through? Easier just to find the app in the app drawer and "restart" it.

I looked, first on playstore, then just searched the internet at large for something that would simply limit the number of recent cards on that screen to, say 5. Whenever you have 5 cards (or 10 or whatever) and you open a new app, the oldest would disappear.

I found a bunch of stuff that would "kill" an app or *all* apps, but this is counterproductive in my case, right? Doing this would reduce battery charge life because I would be using resources to turn it off, then use more resources to create a new instance of it the next time I want to use it—as opposed to just letting it sleep, where it uses very little resources and comes back to life quickly.

---

Bonus, same thing goes for her Chrome browser. *63 open tabs??!!??!!* I found [how to close all open tabs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62319/how-do-i-close-all-tabs-in-chrome-for-android), but it would be nice to only have the 5 most recents there and remove the older ones.

Comment: While it might (or might not) affect the answer, could you also state the phone model and Android version, and whether it's rooted? While I don't yet know the solution for this issue, changing the behavior of the system usually needs root access (or perhaps Magisk for systemless root modification). On the other hand, my Nexus 5 on LineageOS 14.1 aggressively limits the recent apps list instead, so having more than 7 apps shown on there is already a rare situation.

Comment: Without root on Android 7 the possibility to configure something related to the recents menu is next to non-existent. Only on Android 9+ the launcher app can influence the recents menu: https://www.xda-developers.com/android-pie-recent-apps-customization/. Regarding Chrome: If you see real tabs (not just a counter) try to long press the close-x of a tab to get the close-all-tabs menu.